# Abnormal behaviour when reading data using pandas in spark cluster mode

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I have my dataset located in google cloud platform. I am using pandas(new version) to read the data.
The dataset is ranging from **2016-01-01(min date) to 2019-11-31(max date)**. I submitted my job through spark cluster mode and tried to get the max and min date from the dataset. In the first run, I got different max date. The expected is **2019-11-31 but I got 2018-12-31** but when I run next time I get the expected results. This is happening every day.My first run doesn't give expected output but my second run gives. **Is it a spark cluster problem when using pandas to read the data from google cloud platform?**
Below is the code working in client mode but working abnormally in the cluster mode.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("gs://location.csv")
print('min date')
print(min(df.date)) # expected : 2016-01-01
print('max date')   
print(max(df.date)) # expected : 2019-11-31
```